# How force close another application

Tags: java, android

I need force close another application without autorestart it.

I try next steps, application will closed but after few seconds application autorestart (I think this is system protection any applications for craches):

```
// try 1
try
  {
    Method forceStopPackage;
    ActivityManager activityManager = ((ActivityManager)contextService.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
    forceStopPackage = activityManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod( "forceStopPackage", String.class);
    forceStopPackage.setAccessible( true);
    forceStopPackage.invoke( activityManager, sApplicationPackageName);
  }
 catch( Exception e) {}


// try 2
Process           localProcessKill          = null;
DataOutputStream  localDataOutputStreamKill = null;
DataInputStream   localDataInputStreamKill  = null;
try
  {
    localProcessKill          = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su");
    localDataOutputStreamKill = new DataOutputStream( localProcessKill.getOutputStream());
    localDataInputStreamKill  = new DataInputStream(  localProcessKill.getInputStream());
    if( (localDataOutputStreamKill != null) && (localDataInputStreamKill != null))
      {
        localDataOutputStreamKill.writeBytes( "kill -9 " + processInfo.pid + "\n");
        localDataOutputStreamKill.flush();
        localDataOutputStreamKill.writeBytes( "exit\n");
        localDataOutputStreamKill.flush();
        // localProcessKill.waitFor();
      }
  }
 catch( Exception e) {}


// try 3
try
  {
    activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses( processInfo.processName);
  }
 catch( Exception e) {}


// try 4
try
  {
    android.os.Process.sendSignal( processInfo.pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
  }
 catch( Exception e) {}
```

But killed application self- restarting.
Please get me any ideas about force stop another application without restarting.

Answer (score 2):

since you have root permission, you can try the adb command for stopping an app:

```
adb shell am force-stop APP_PACKAGE
```